# How to add single form in three tab using netzke tabpanel and only one save button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, extjs, netzke

Please any one help me..

How to add single form in three tab using netzke tabpanel and only one save button.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nest your fields in a tabpanel, and put the tabpanel inside the form.